# Import local packages as modules not in the React-Native project

Tags: react-native, webpack, lerna

In a React-Native project, I found that if your local package has a valid `package.json` file, you can import that like a module in `node_modules` without a relative path .

For example,

```
app/                             # a React-Native project
  |- any_folder_for_packages/
  |   |- foo/
  |       |- package.json
  |       |- index.js
  |- src/
  |   |- bar/
  |       |- bar.js
  |- ...
```

In this case, you can import the package `foo` in the `bar.js` using either:

```js
// with a relative path
import foo from '../../any_folder_for_packages/foo';
```

or

```js
// like a module (without a relative path)
import foo from 'foo';
```

The packager will try to find and use any local module which contains a `package.json` matching the requirement.

## The question

I have a local package which is not in the React-Native project, how can I import it

```
projects/
  |- app/                # a React-Native project
  |   |- src/
  |   |   |- bar/
  |   |       |- bar.js  # need to import the package foo as a module which is not in this project
  |   |- ...
  |- other_paths/
      |- foo/
          |- package.json
          |- index.js
```

I tried to use

```js
// like a module (without a relative path)
import foo from 'foo';
```

but it failed to find the module.

How can I use `react-native` to find the package when packing for development or bundling for the production?

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @Plague doesn't work in react native. You have to configure your metro.config.js file to use a local package.

**If Using Expo**

In expo, metro.config.js file may not be visible, so in the root directory of your project, run this command;

```
npx expo customize metro.config.js
```

This will generate the file for you with some default configuration. Now to import any package, you have to modify two things here;

`config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths`, to include the package, and ;
`config.watchFolders` to keep a watch on the package.

In nutshell, `metro.config.js` file should be like this;

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

const packagePath = "/full/path/to/package";

// here i added the packagePath to the list in the configuration to include it    
config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths.push(packagePath);

// here i added the package again to another configuration key, to keep a watch on it if we make any changes.
config.watchFolders.push(packagePath);

module.exports = config;
```

That is it, but your code editor may report that module is not found, for that warning to remove, you can just run the command below;

```
npm install /path/to/package
```

**BUT there is a problem with this**

The dependencies in our package conflicts with that of main project.

So here is another way of installing a local package.

**Using install-local**

For this we don't need to make any changes to any file. We just need to install this package;

```
npm install install-local
```

And then install the local package using this;

```
npx install-local --save path/to/package
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to make your application aware of it through your root `package.json` files.

Confirm the *new* local module has a basic `package.json` configured.

For example:

```
{
  "name": "foo", 
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Ensure the package has an index.js and that it has something exported or export default.

For example, at the bottom of the `index.js`:

`export default foo;`

Then, simply save the package as a project dependency in your root module to via NPM.  To do this and install it automatically into your `node_modules` you can use this command.

```
npm install --save file:other_paths/foo
```

**note** make sure you have the correct relative path from your *general project* `package.json` to your *new* module `package.json`.

Example, in this case it would be:

```
app/                          # a React-Native project root
  |- other_paths/  
  |   |- foo/
  |      |- package.json      # new module package json
  |      |- index.js
  |- src/
  |   |- bar/
  |       |- bar.js
  |- package.json             # project package json
```

If set up correctly you should then be able reference the module anywhere in your project without relative path.

`import Foo from 'foo';`

Comment: I can confirm this did not work. It only produces a "module not found" error. Either the instructions are wrong or incomplete.

Comment: @FirzokNadeem ... I've revised the answer, hopefully this helps.

Comment: @user1258361 ... I've revised the answer, hopefully this helps.